# "back to normal"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The situation this morning is better, and nearly **back to normal**.

That sentence is from my grammar book. How to understand it correctly? "Back" is a verb here or an adverb? If it is an adverb, it means that the full sentence is:

> The situation this morning is better, and **it is** nearly **back to normal**.

Could you explain it please?

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary? It will tell you that "back" can mean *to return*. That would make it clear how it is being used in the context of your example.

Comment: Note, there are some usages of "back" that really are verbs, but they don't apply here. It could mean "to move backward" (*back the truck in here*) or "to support someone or something" (*the bill is backed by a senior senator*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *back* is an adjective, connected to the subject by *is*.

[Merriam-Webster *back*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/back)
adjective 2: having returned or been returned

*to normal* is a preposition phrase.

If you use *back* with another verb, like *to go back*, it's an adverb. (See the M-W definition of the adverb use.)

Comment: This is the right track, though I'd simply say "*back to normal* is an adjectival phrase."

Comment: I agree it's an adjective phrase, but there are other possibilities with *back* - back home, back to work, back in the saddle, back to bed, back to the USSR etc. So, the adjective *back* can be combined with many preposition phrases. There's no reason to think of it as an unbreakable unit.